# accessing static variables in method

Tags: apex, controller, static

I have static variables declared outside class and i am instantiating the variables in one method and access the same value in other method.But in spite of variable being set to static its still giving me null.

```
Public Class PolicyHolderDetails { 

Public Static ID PolId{get;set;}
Public Static ID Nameid{get;set;}
Public void CheckInsurance(){

Policy__c Pid=[select id from policy__c where Policy_Name__c='Health Insurance'][0];
     PolId=Pid.id;//setting the values..
     system.debug(PolId);
}
Public void Save(){ 
Account aa=[Select id from Account where name=:Name][0];
 Nameid=aa.id;
 system.debug(Nameid);
}
Public PageReference SaveAgreement() {
PolicyHolderDetails pobj=new PolicyHolderDetails();
//pobj.CheckInsurance();
//pobj.Save();
id pid=PolicyHolderDetails.PolId;//accessing the variables here..
id Nid=PolicyHolderDetails.Nameid;
}
}
```

Comment: I hope you are calling CheckInsurance() & save() method before trying to get values from Static variable. 
I see those commented in your code.

Comment: No..because it is a static variable i am directly calling from class name.

Comment: are you sure your SaveAgreement is executing only after value is assigned to your static variable?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal - You are calling static variables correctly but before calling them you are have to assign values to those variables. As I can see in your code you are populating values in these static variables in CheckInsurance() & save() methods so If you want to get values from these static variables your method calling sequence should me like: 


PolicyHolderDetails obj = new PolicyHolderDetails();
// Call these methods first from somewhere so that values can be assgined to static variables.
obj.CheckInsurance();
obj.Save();

// Now try to get values.
obj.SaveAgreement();

Comment: but those variables are declared static so no need to call them through method().Static variables has property that their values remain same through out the class

Comment: Yes @salesforceDeveloper..The value is set and then called..Even in that method i am getting the value in debug but when its coming to that method its showing null

Answer (score 1):

When a page invokes a method the view state - the values of the fields of the class - are automatically re-populated immediately before the method runs. But `static` variables are not part of that mechanism (by design). Removing `Static` from the declarations and referencing them as normal non-static variables in `SaveAgreement` should address the problem.

More detail in e.g. [An Introduction to Visualforce View State](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State).

**PS**

The simplest solution is to just do everything in the `SaveAgreement` method:

```
Public PageReference SaveAgreement() {

   Policy__c Pid=[select id from policy__c where Policy_Name__c='Health Insurance'][0];
   Id PolId = Pid.id;
   Account aa = [Select id from Account where name=:Name][0];
   Id Nameid = aa.id;

   ... just use the PolId and Nameid local variables here ...
}
```

but if you need to keep the logic spread across the 3 mthods:

```
Public Class PolicyHolderDetails { 

    Public ID PolId{get;set;}
    Public ID NameId{get;set;}

    Public void CheckInsurance(){
        Policy__c Pid=[select id from policy__c where Policy_Name__c='Health Insurance'][0];
        PolId = Pid.id;
    }

    Public void Save(){ 
        Account aa=[Select id from Account where name=:Name][0];
        NameId = aa.id;
    }

    Public PageReference SaveAgreement() {
        ... reference the PolId and NameId fields here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I even tried it without static by  creating object and accessing them..Still iam getting null.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Don't have them static. Hard to say what is going on otherwise - the methods of your controller aren't too clear and you haven't explained much about the page and what order those methods are called in.

Comment: Ok let me explain you.Actually the code is very big so i have not kept everything​..So i have declared 2 variables.And the var are getting instantiated in CheckInsurance() and save() method..Now i need to access those values inside 3rd method Saveagreement ().For keeping values same throughout the class i used static..If there is any other option pls suggest me..i even tried without static...The order they are called are CheckIns(),Save() & Saveagreement ()

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Non-static is the way to go. Read the link I included in the answer and create a simple page/controller example to see that the mechanism works and then go back to your more complicated example and debug it.

Comment: Pls can you help me with code actually its something urgent and i have tried everything...

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal I've added a bit to the answer; that is my lot on this - good luck.